# How to change background only to some words in a textView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, nsattributedstring

I need to change the background color of some particular words in a text that stay in a textView. Something similar to what happens in Firefox when you seearch for a word... So lets say I have a textView with this text

> "A man is sitting in front of my porch and another man is calling him"

and I want to change background color to the 2 occurence of the word

> "**man**"

... how could I do that?
I know that there is NSAttributedString to do this kind of things but I can not understand how to modify only some particular words... in the examples I found Googling it there were only examples of how to change the first 5 characters or things like this...

Comment: That can be done easily.  But what have you done so far as long as writing code is concerned?

Comment: Look at NSMutableAttributedString : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsmutableattributedstring_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSMutableAttributedString* attrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: @"Your String"];
NSUInteger count = 0;
NSUInteger length = [attrString length];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, length);

while(range.location != NSNotFound)
{
    range = [[attrString string] rangeOfString:@"YOURWORD" options:0 range:range];
    if(range.location != NSNotFound) {
        [attrString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName value:YOURCOLOR range:NSMakeRange(range.location, [word length])];
        range = NSMakeRange(range.location + range.length, length - (range.location + range.length));
        count++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't do anything... maybe I'm doing something wrong...
I did this:  I changed "initWithString: @"Your String"];" with "initWithString: [myTextView string]];"..... "rangeOfString:@"YOURWORD"" with "rangeOfString:word" and at the begin I added "NSString *word = @"button";".... in myTextView there is the word "button" but when I execute this code nothing happens... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Ok, I found out what I was missing... I had to add the attrString to my textView... I did it with this and it seams it works good: [[myTextView textStorage] setAttributedString:attrString];